# XCTest: Can not get the last collection cell element after swipeLeft()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I have one collection View inside my table view cell. And I want to tap on the last cell after swipe left to see the last collection cell.

For example here are my list collection view cells:

> ```
>           |A  B  C  D| E F
> ```
>
> Note: '|' is the bounds of screen and collection cell E, F are not visible yet

```
     let tableCell = app.tables["TableView"].cells.element(boundBy: 1)

  // Test to get the label of collection cell inside tableCell
     let collectionCell_A = tableCell.staticTexts["A"]
     XCTAssert(collectionCell_A.exists) // Okay

  // Swipe left to see the collection cell E
     tableCell.swipeLeft()

  // Test to get collection cell D success
     let sevenElevenCell = tableCell.staticTexts["D"]

  // But with the collection cell E always failed.
     let collectionCell_E = tableCell.staticTexts["E"]
     waitUntilElementExists(collectionCell_E) // My helper func to wait element exits for 10 seconds
     collectionCell_E.tap() // Failed here
```

After debugging, I found that list staticTexts didn't update after collection has swiped to left.

I think this guy has the same problem like me. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82366

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. My co-worker has a great solution to fix it.

```
let cell = XCUIApplication().cells.containing(NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS %@", "E")).element

cell.tap()              // Success.
```

Hope this will help someone else.